# change phy# index of wireless devices

Tags: wireless

I want to know if it is possible to change the phy# index of wireless devices. Right now I have two wireless devices with this information:

```
elans@elans-TravelMate-P446-M:~$ iw dev
phy#1
    Unnamed/non-netdev interface
        wdev 0x100000002
        addr X:X:X:X:X:X
        type P2P-device
        txpower 0.00 dBm
    Interface wlp4s0
        ifindex 4
        wdev 0x100000001
        addr X:X:X:X:X:X
        ssid EGR Wi-Fi
        type managed
        channel 40 (5200 MHz), width: 80 MHz, center1: 5210 MHz
        txpower 30.00 dBm
phy#0
    Interface wlp2s0
        ifindex 3
        wdev 0x1
        addr X:X:X:X:X:X
        type managed
```

I want the device with `phy#0` to be renamed to `phy#2`. Is it possible to do so? I have already tried `sudo iw phy#0  set name phy#2` but this command seems to change the name, not the index.

This is the output of `sudo lshw -class network`:

```
  *-network DISABLED      
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Wil6200 802.11ad Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Wilocity Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlp2s0
       version: 02
       serial: X:X:X:X:X:X
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=wil6210 driverversion=4.17.0 firmware=5.2.0.18 latency=0 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:53 memory:c1200000-c13fffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0.1
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.1
       logical name: enp3s0f1
       version: 14
       serial: X:X:X:X:X:X
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl8411-2_0.0.1 07/08/13 ip=192.168.4.3 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:18 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:c1404000-c1404fff memory:c1400000-c1403fff
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
       logical name: wlp4s0
       version: 32
       serial: X:X:X:X:X:X
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath10k_pci driverversion=4.17.0 firmware=RM.4.4.1.c2-00057-QCARMSWP-1 ip=35.12.211.177 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:55 memory:c1000000-c11fffff
```

Comment: Don't want to XY your question, but why do you care? I haven't seen anything that actually uses the phy#s for anything beyond reporting. I have an inoperative wireless card in my notebook that wouldn't let me use a USB WiFi until I figured out how to disable it, but it didn't do anything with phy#s.

Comment: @Joe `iw` uses the phy index (and *only* the phy index) for quite a bit beyond reporting.  You can get the phy index from the dev name with `iw`, but with the caveat that you should "NOT screenscrape this tool, we don't consider its output stable".  In any case, it is a fuggly scrape.   Meaning it is a PITA to automate via script anything that requires an `iw` command based on phy index...